# Problems in running marble example offline

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to run this example on my computer without the help of the Blockchain implementation from Bluemix.

https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/marbles/blob/master/tutorial_part1.md#confignetwork

I have downloaded the hyperledger/fabric-peer docker images and set up the corresponding docker-compose.yml file with the correct CORE_PEER_ID and CORE_VM_ENDPOINT.

```
vp0:
  image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
  environment:
    - CORE_PEER_ID=vp0
    - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
    - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=172.17.0.1:2375
    - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
  command: peer node start
```

Now, I try to run the marbles node app with the correct api_host and api_port.

```
var peers = [{
        "api_host": "172.17.0.2", //hostname or ip of peer
        "api_port": 7051, //http port
        "id": "vp0" //unique id of peer
    }];
```

The fabric peer seems to ignore the connection request with the node app and responds with:

```
vp0_1 | 2016/10/13 20:15:03 transport: http2Server.HandleStreams received bogus greeting from client: "POST /registrar HTTP/1.1"
```

I try also to send a GET requests with postman:

```
http://172.17.0.2:7051/chain
```

The response gives

```
vp0_1 | 2016/10/13 20:13:23 transport: http2Server.HandleStreams received bogus greeting from client: "GET /chain HTTP/1.1\r\nHos"
```

Here is the whole output of my GET request

```
Starting capstone_vp0_1
Attaching to capstone_vp0_1
vp0_1 | 20:11:36.771 [logging] LoggingInit -> DEBU 001 Setting default logging level to DEBUG for command 'node'
vp0_1 | 20:11:36.771 [peer] func1 -> INFO 002 Auto detected peer address: 172.17.0.2:7051
vp0_1 | 20:11:36.771 [peer] func1 -> INFO 003 Auto detected peer address: 172.17.0.2:7051
vp0_1 | 20:11:36.772 [eventhub_producer] AddEventType -> DEBU 004 registering BLOCK
vp0_1 | 20:11:36.772 [eventhub_producer] AddEventType -> DEBU 005 registering CHAINCODE
vp0_1 | 20:11:36.772 [eventhub_producer] AddEventType -> DEBU 006 registering REJECTION
vp0_1 | 20:11:36.772 [eventhub_producer] AddEventType -> DEBU 007 registering REGISTER
vp0_1 | 20:11:36.772 [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 008 Security enabled status: false
vp0_1 | 20:11:36.772 [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 009 Privacy enabled status: false
vp0_1 | 20:11:36.772 [eventhub_producer] start -> INFO 00a event processor started
vp0_1 | 20:11:36.772 [db] open -> DEBU 00b Is db path [/var/hyperledger/production/db] empty [false]
vp0_1 | 20:11:36.985 [chaincode] NewChaincodeSupport -> INFO 00c Chaincode support using peerAddress: 172.17.0.2:7051
vp0_1 | 20:11:36.986 [chaincode] NewChaincodeSupport -> DEBU 00d Turn off keepalive(value 0)
vp0_1 | 20:11:36.986 [sysccapi] RegisterSysCC -> INFO 00e system chaincode (noop,github.com/hyperledger/fabric/bddtests/syschaincode/noop) disabled
vp0_1 | 20:11:36.986 [nodeCmd] serve -> DEBU 00f Running as validating peer - making genesis block if needed
vp0_1 | 20:11:36.986 [state] loadConfig -> INFO 010 Loading configurations...
vp0_1 | 20:11:36.986 [state] loadConfig -> INFO 011 Configurations loaded. stateImplName=[buckettree], stateImplConfigs=map[numBuckets:%!s(int=1000003) maxGroupingAtEachLevel:%!s(int=5) bucketCacheSize:%!s(int=100)], deltaHistorySize=[500]
vp0_1 | 20:11:36.986 [state] NewState -> INFO 012 Initializing state implementation [buckettree]
vp0_1 | 20:11:36.986 [buckettree] initConfig -> INFO 013 configs passed during initialization = map[string]interface {}{"numBuckets":1000003, "maxGroupingAtEachLevel":5, "bucketCacheSize":100}
vp0_1 | 20:11:36.986 [buckettree] initConfig -> INFO 014 Initializing bucket tree state implemetation with configurations &{maxGroupingAtEachLevel:5 lowestLevel:9 levelToNumBucketsMap:map[2:13 3:65 9:1000003 1:3 8:200001 6:8001 4:321 7:40001 5:1601 0:1] hashFunc:0xab4560}
vp0_1 | 20:11:36.986 [buckettree] newBucketCache -> INFO 015 Constructing bucket-cache with max bucket cache size = [100] MBs
vp0_1 | 20:11:36.986 [buckettree] loadAllBucketNodesFromDB -> INFO 016 Loaded buckets data in cache. Total buckets in DB = [0]. Total cache size:=0
vp0_1 | 20:11:36.987 [nodeCmd] serve -> DEBU 017 Running as validating peer - installing consensus 
vp0_1 | 20:11:36.987 [peer] initDiscovery -> DEBU 018 Retrieved discovery list from disk: []
vp0_1 | 20:11:36.987 [consensus/controller] NewConsenter -> INFO 019 Creating default consensus plugin (noops)
vp0_1 | 20:11:36.988 [consensus/noops] newNoops -> DEBU 01a Creating a NOOPS object
vp0_1 | 20:11:36.988 [consensus/noops] newNoops -> INFO 01b NOOPS consensus type = *noops.Noops
vp0_1 | 20:11:36.988 [consensus/noops] newNoops -> INFO 01c NOOPS block size = 500
vp0_1 | 20:11:36.988 [consensus/noops] newNoops -> INFO 01d NOOPS block wait = 1s
vp0_1 | 20:11:36.988 [peer] chatWithSomePeers -> DEBU 01e Starting up the first peer of a new network
vp0_1 | 20:11:36.988 [consensus/statetransfer] verifyAndRecoverBlockchain -> DEBU 01f Validating existing blockchain, highest validated block is 0, valid through 0
vp0_1 | 20:11:36.988 [consensus/statetransfer] blockThread -> INFO 021 Validated blockchain to the genesis block
vp0_1 | 20:11:36.988 [consensus/handler] 1 -> DEBU 020 Starting up message thread for consenter
vp0_1 | 20:11:36.988 [rest] StartOpenchainRESTServer -> INFO 022 Initializing the REST service on 0.0.0.0:7050, TLS is disabled.
vp0_1 | 20:11:36.988 [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 023 Starting peer with ID=name:"vp0" , network ID=dev, address=172.17.0.2:7051, rootnodes=, validator=true
vp0_1 | 20:11:36.988 [peer] ensureConnected -> DEBU 024 Starting Peer reconnect service (touch service), with period = 6s
vp0_1 | 20:11:42.989 [peer] ensureConnected -> DEBU 025 Touch service indicates no dropped connections
vp0_1 | 20:11:42.989 [peer] ensureConnected -> DEBU 026 Connected to: []
vp0_1 | 20:11:42.989 [peer] ensureConnected -> DEBU 027 Discovery knows about: []
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error message because you are using the wrong port (7051 is actually the grpc port) while sending the REST request.

The default rest API port for the hyperledger fabric peer is **7050**. So your GET request should be: 
http://172.17.0.2:7050/chain

The port in use by the peer for the REST interface can be verified by noting the  following log entry (seen in your log)

```
vp0_1 | 20:11:36.988 [rest] StartOpenchainRESTServer -> INFO 022 Initializing the REST service on 0.0.0.0:7050, TLS is disabled.
```